# ASP.NET (4.5) GridView binding to dynamically-generated SQL query, with paging and sorting?

Tags: asp.net, gridview

I'm using VS 2013 (latest version) and an ASP.NET 4.5 WebForms application. I need to run SQL commands that return data, but that's all I know about the SQL at runtime. I want to bind the result at runtime to a GridView and have it auto-generate columns. I also want it to support sorting and paging.

I've researched this ad nauseam, and I find tons of examples that refer to one part of this, but nothing that appears to allow all aspects at once.

Isn't there some easy way to do this? It would seem to me that I should just be able to bind the data to the grid, and let it take care of everything else.

FYI, the SQL commands in question are stored in a table in the database, along with information about parameters (if any). My web app allows the user to select one of these SQL commands, facilitates entering parameter information, and lets the user run the query to export it to different formats or even run a Crystal Report for it. So that's why I don't know anything about the SQL at runtime. In case you cared. :)

EDIT:

So here is what I came up with. Please note that I removed a bunch of code that is related to my logic that isn't really relevant to this discussion, so this may not compile, but it should give you the idea.

```
<asp:GridView runat="server" ID="gridView1" CssClass="XG_DataTable" 
                AllowSorting="true" AllowPaging="true" PageSize="20"
                OnPageIndexChanging="gridView1_OnPageIndexChanging"
                OnSorting="gridView1_OnSorting"
                AutoGenerateColumns="true">
</asp:GridView>
```

...

```
public partial class ViewGrid
{
    private bool SortAscending
    {
        get
        {
            var result = ViewState["SortAscending"];
            return (result == null) || ((bool) result);
        }
        set { ViewState["SortAscending"] = value; }
    }

    private string SortExpression
    {
        get
        {
            var result = ViewState["SortExpression"];
            return result == null ? "" : result.ToString();
        }
        set
        {
            if (value == SortExpression)
                SortAscending = !SortAscending;
            else
            {
                ViewState["SortExpression"] = value;
                SortAscending = true;
            }
        }
    }

    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        BindGridView();
    }

    private void BindGridView()
    {
        gridView1.DataSource = GetData();
        gridView1.DataBind();
    }

    private object GetData()
    {
        var dataTable = GetUnsortedData();

        var sortExpression = SortExpression;
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(sortExpression))
            return dataTable;

        var dv = new DataView(dataTable);
        dv.Sort = string.Format("{0} {1}", sortExpression, SortAscending ? "asc" : "desc");
        return dv;
    }

    private DataTable GetUnsortedData()
    {
        // retrieve the data from the database
    }

    protected void gridView1_OnPageIndexChanging(object sender, GridViewPageEventArgs e)
    {
        gridView1.PageIndex = e.NewPageIndex;
        BindGridView();
    }

    protected void gridView1_OnSorting(object sender, GridViewSortEventArgs e)
    {
        SortExpression = e.SortExpression;
        BindGridView();
    }
}
```

Comment: How do you bind your data? Do you use a SQLDataSource or ObjectDataSource Control to bind your data to the grid? Or do you retrieve the data in code behind and assign it as datasource to the gridview manually?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a sample

**HTMl markup:**

```
<asp:GridView runat="server" AllowPaging="true" AllowSorting="true"     
id="mygrid" AutoGenerateColumns="true"></asp:GridView>
```

You can set **PageSize** for number of rows from the data source to display per page.

**C#**

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
       if (!Page.IsPostBack)
       {
          gvBind(); //Bind gridview
       }
}

public void gvBind()
{    SqlDataAdapter dap = new SqlDataAdapter("select query", conn);
     DataSet ds = new DataSet();
     dap.Fill(ds);
     mygrid.DataSource = ds.Tables[0];
     mygrid.DataBind();
}

protected void PageIndexChanging(object sender, GridViewPageEventArgs e)
{
       mygrid.PageIndex = e.NewPageIndex;
       gvBind();
}
```

Comment: Thank you. I had to do some work to figure out sorting, but your post got be going the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

Get the data in a dataset and set the gridview datasource to that dataset.

Frontend

```
<asp:GridView runat="server" AllowPaging="true" AllowSorting="true"     id="mygrid" AutoGenerateColumns="true"></asp:GridView>
```

Then code behind

```
 mygrid.DataSource = dataset
           mygrid.DataBind();
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. When I do that and click on a page number, I get an error: "The GridView 'gridView1' fired event PageIndexChanging which wasn't handled".

Comment: Handle the  PageIndexChanging event , a lot of examples online, search

Comment: That's *exactly* my point. If I handle the PageIndexChanging event, then I either have to add paging parameters to the SQL query, which I can't do because the SQL comes from a table, or I have to write code to do the paging, and that's why I asked the question in the first place.